# passing whole datatable from view to the controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the view below:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display mobile_dt1" id="SearchResults">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*   <input type="checkbox" name="Test" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('PartialViewName')" *@
            <th id="CHCKID" class="checkBoxClass">Check All @Html.CheckBox("checkboxall", new { @id = "checkall", @name = "StatusList" })</th>
            <th>Export</th>
            <th>Request ID</th>
            <th id="RQSTNMSRCHID" style="display: none">@BVPConstants.RQSTNMSRCH</th>
            <th id="RQSTSTTSSRCHID">@BVPConstants.RQSTSTTSSRCH</th>
            <th>Strategic Initiative</th>
            <th id="BSNGRPL1ID">@BVPConstants.BSNGRPL1</th>
            <th id="EXCTVSPNSRID">@BVPConstants.EXCTVSPNSR</th>
            <th id="RQSTCLSFNID">@BVPConstants.RQSTCLSFN</th>
            <th id="BUSNDBYDTID">@BVPConstants.BUSNDBYDT</th>
            <th id="CRTDBYSRCHID">@BVPConstants.CRTDBYSRCH</th>
            <th id="CRTDONID">@BVPConstants.CRTDON</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
        foreach (var SearchResult in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="chck">@Html.CheckBox("checkboxall", new { @id = "check" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionImage("", "", new { @Id = "export" }, null, null, null, "~/Content/img/ico/filePDFUpload.png", "Download")</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(SearchResult.RequestId.ToString(), "Edit", "BusinessRequest", new { requestId = SearchResult.RequestId }, new { @onerror = "closeLoading()", @onload = "closeLoading()", @onclick = "showLoading()" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(SearchResult.RequestName.ToString(), "Edit", "BusinessRequest", new { requestId = SearchResult.RequestId }, new { @onerror = "closeLoading()", @onload = "closeLoading()", @onclick = "showLoading()" }) </td>
            <td>@SearchResult.Status</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.StrategicInitiativeNumber</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.BusinessGroup</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.ExecutiveSponsorNumber</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.RequestClassification</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.BusinessNeedByDate</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.CreatedBy</td>
            <td>@SearchResult.CRTTs</td>
        </tr>
        }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to send the SearchResults datatable to the below controller method:

```
public PartialViewResult ExportToExcel(DataTable table) {
    List<SearchRequestModel> srchlist = new List<SearchRequestModel>();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var grid = new GridView();

    grid.DataSource = table;
    grid.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Prioritization.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    grid.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();

    return PartialView("_SearchHistory", srchlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Action Method parameter maps automatically the Request.Form. That said, you will only be able to make your DataTable parameter work (has values) if you have form fields in your table.

Since you don't want to allow the user to edit the data I would recommend you to use hidden fields. You can do them either "manually" (`<input type="hidden" />`) or use the MVC Html helper (`@Html.HiddenFor()`).

Comment: I want to send the datatable on click of Export to excel button. Please help.